# Unity Multiple Assembly Definition Files Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, assemblies

I am a beginner in Unity and when I was working on a project I had the error **Folder 'Assets/JMO Assets/Toony Colors Pro/Demo TCP2/Common Demo Assets/Kino Bloom/Editor/' contains multiple assembly definition files (Assets/JMO Assets/Toony Colors Pro/Demo TCP2/Common Demo Assets/Kino Bloom/Editor/CFXR Demo Editor.asmdef)**. I have no idea about assemblies and when I researched I couldn't understand how to fix the error. How can I fix it?

here are the codes for the two assembly scripts

First One:

```
    "references": [
        "CFXRDemo"
    ],
    "includePlatforms": [],
    "excludePlatforms": [
        "Android",
        "CloudRendering",
        "iOS",
        "LinuxStandalone64",
        "Lumin",
        "macOSStandalone",
        "PS4",
        "Stadia",
        "Switch",
        "tvOS",
        "WSA",
        "WebGL",
        "WindowsStandalone32",
        "WindowsStandalone64",
        "XboxOne"
    ],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [],
    "noEngineReferences": false
```

Second One:

```
 "name": "ToonyColorsPro.Demo.Editor",
    "references": [
        "ToonyColorsPro2.Demo"
    ],
    "includePlatforms": [],
    "excludePlatforms": [
        "Android",
        "CloudRendering",
        "iOS",
        "LinuxStandalone64",
        "Lumin",
        "macOSStandalone",
        "PS4",
        "Stadia",
        "Switch",
        "tvOS",
        "WSA",
        "WebGL",
        "WindowsStandalone32",
        "WindowsStandalone64",
        "XboxOne"
    ],
    "allowUnsafeCode": false,
    "overrideReferences": false,
    "precompiledReferences": [],
    "autoReferenced": true,
    "defineConstraints": [],
    "versionDefines": [],
    "noEngineReferences": false
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! If you don't specifically use that language don't use that tag.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you need to delete one of these Assembly Definition Files because a folder can't have more than one.

If this error showed up after updating your asset, then it is possible that the author has renamed the Assembly Definition File in the latest update and it resulted in 2 Assembly Definition Files in your project. I'd recommend you to delete the '*Assets/JMO Assets/Toony Colors Pro/Demo TCP2/Common Demo Assets/Kino Bloom/Editor/*' folder and then reimport only that folder from Asset Store (i.e. deselect all other assets in the import dialogue).

Comment: @divonia so you said thank you and this comment also helped me I think you should mark it and up vote it as yasirkula gave their time to help you ...

Comment: @CrandellWS i dont have enough rep to up vote it